# sqlite join select will necessary fully scan a table?

Tags: sqlite

here is my case:

```
CREATE TABLE estimateperiod(estimatePeriodId int, periodTypeId int, companyId int, fiscalChainSeriesId int, fiscalQuarter int,fiscalYear int, calendarQuarter int, calendarYear int, periodEndDate datetime,advanceDate datetime);

CREATE INDEX estimateperiod_estimateperiodid_companyid on estimateperiod(estimateperiodid, companyid);

CREATE TABLE isinenhancedsymbol(symbolid int, symboltypeid int, symbolvalue char(64), relatedcompanyid char(64), exchangeid int, objectid int, symbolstartdate date, symbolenddate date, activeflag int);

CREATE INDEX isinenhancedsymbol_relatedcompanyid_isin on isinenhancedsymbol(relatedcompanyid, symbolvalue);
```

when I run this:

```
sqlite> explain query plan **select ep.estimateperiodid, ep.companyid , isin.symbolvalue from estimateperiod ep, isinenhancedsymbol isin where ep.estimateperiodid = 100 and ep.companyid = isin.relatedcompanyid;**
orde  from           deta
----  -------------  ----
0     1              TABLE isinenhancedsymbol AS isin
1     0              TABLE estimateperiod AS ep WITH INDEX estimateperiod_estimateperiodid_companyid
```

So, isinenhancedsymbol table is fully scanned, this cost long time. All fields in select are in covering index, why isinenhancedsymbol cannot be searched using the index?

Comment: Which SQLite version?

Comment: version 3.6.20, is there any problem for this version?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite version 3.6.20 is quite a few years out of date.

Covering indexes are supported with any somewhat current version:

```
sqlite> .eqp on
sqlite> select ep.estimateperiodid, ep.companyid , isin.symbolvalue from estimateperiod ep, isinenhancedsymbol isin where ep.estimateperiodid = 100 and ep.companyid = isin.relatedcompanyid;
--EQP-- 0,0,0,SEARCH TABLE estimateperiod AS ep USING COVERING INDEX estimateperiod_estimateperiodid_companyid (estimatePeriodId=?)
--EQP-- 0,1,1,SCAN TABLE isinenhancedsymbol AS isin USING COVERING INDEX isinenhancedsymbol_relatedcompanyid_isin
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. About the query plan, I want to ask why the table isin cannot be searched by index, rather than scan table?  scan table is quite slow, how this sql can be optimized?

Comment: "Scan" just means that all rows are read (in the table's or index's order). If all rows are needed anyway, reading them in random order would be much slower.

Comment: I mean: why this sql not run in this way: 
first: search table ep by index estimateperiod_estimateperiodid_companyid, find the rows that estimateperiodid = 100, and get the corresponding companyid
second: search table isin by index isinenhancedsymbol_relatedcompanyid_isin, find the rows that relatedcompanyid = ep.companyid
I think this will be much quicker.